# Angular2: ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using angular/cli 1.3.2 and Angular 4.4.0.
When I use an npm module `angular-split@0.2.2`,during compilation I met

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 194:50 in
>   the original .ts file), resolving symbol NgModule in
>   path-to-project/node_modules/angular-split/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol AngularSplitModule in
>   path-to-project/node_modules/angular-split/dist/angularSplit.module.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol AngularSplitModule in
>   path-to-project/node_modules/angular-split/dist/angularSplit.module.d.ts

Here in file `angularSplit.module.d.ts` there is only one line of code:

`export declare class AngularSplitModule {}`

However, this error can be "resolved" by saving any file and trigger the recompile (weird).

Then, when I open `localhost:4200` in the browser I will see another error:

`compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularSplitModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

From github and stackoverflow I found some similar problems but no one could tell the reason.

This happened after I updated node/angular/angular-cli, but after I roll back it still didn't work.

Does anyone know why this happened?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright, after hours of reading I found one useful solution here
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3854#issuecomment-274344771

to be specific, add
`paths: { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] }`
to `tsconfig.json` file, `"compilerOptions"` option

It solves my problem but still wanna know why.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got the same error and now fixed after seeing this.

Comment: We spent an entire afternoon looking for this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: any luck finding why it needs it ?

Comment: My issue didn't solved with this fix. Actually I am trying initiate a service when the angular app loads and for that I am calling function of service from app.module.ts and that's why the error.

Comment: fixed my problem to but I want to know why

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered the below error:

> ERROR in solving symbol values statically. Expression form not
>   supported (position 30:19 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol
>   AppModule in /.../src/app/app.module.ts

In app.module.ts, the code was not formatted properly:

Earlier:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,,
    ]
```

Corrected it to:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [    
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ]
```

And it worked. Might be useful for anyone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was working with Teams , What I noticed after research that the component was not part of the chain,

> NO BLUE LOCK SYMBOL

So first find all folders that has no blue lock symbol (IN CASE YOU USING SOURCE CONTROL) include them and check in those components

The Error was

[image]

[image]

SOLUTION is to add in source control first then check in

[image]